# Swift creating NSError Object

Tags: ios, swift, nserror

I am trying to create an error object to display to the user.

```
let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = 
    [
    "NSLocalizedDescriptionKey" :  NSLocalizedString("Unauthorized", comment: ""),
    "NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey" : NSLocalizedString("Unauthorized", comment: "")
    ]
let err = NSError(domain: "ShiploopHttpResponseErrorDomain", code: httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo: userInfo)
print("Error in Post: \(err.localizedDescription)")
```

Unfortunately the output is:

```
Error in Post: The operation couldn’t be completed.(ShiploopHttpResponseErrorDomain error 401.)
```

I want to be able to show to the user that he should activate his account. Any ideas??

Answer (score 44):

Looks like you want (see dictionary keys):

> Swift 2

```
let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] =
[
    NSLocalizedDescriptionKey :  NSLocalizedString("Unauthorized", value: "Please activate your account", comment: ""),
    NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : NSLocalizedString("Unauthorized", value: "Account not activated", comment: "")
]
```

> Swift 3

```
let userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any] =
            [
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey :  NSLocalizedString("Unauthorized", value: "Please activate your account", comment: "") ,
                NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : NSLocalizedString("Unauthorized", value: "Account not activated", comment: "")
        ]
```

Then create the error object in both swift 2 or 3 like this:

```
let err = NSError(domain: "ShiploopHttpResponseErrorDomain", code: 401, userInfo: userInfo)
println("Error in Post: \(err.localizedDescription)")
```

NSLocalizedDescriptionKey and NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey are global String variables, and the keys inside of the userInfo dictionary. The values are slightly different from what you specified:

```
println(NSLocalizedDescriptionKey) //prints "NSLocalizedDescription"
println(NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey) //prints "NSLocalizedFailureReason"
```

I find it good practice to look at the documentation by right-clicking the class (NSError in this case) and selecting "Jump To Definition" within xcode.  All kinds of questions can be answered this way. :)

Comment: It might also make sense to create your own error class by inheriting from NSError and then overriding the getter for localizedDescription.

Comment: The thing is I should subclass NSError to be able to custom "NSLocalizedDescriptionKey" to show my custom message. I am new to Swift and programming. So I will have to dig to know how to Implement this :) thx for your response

Answer (score 40):

Creating a very simple error in Swift 3:

```
let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Object does not exist"])
```

Answer (score 21):

Creating an error is as simple as following line:

```
let error = NSError(domain: "com.example.error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "message"])
```

If you need additional stack trace information, use following method:

```
func error(_ message: String, code: Int = 0, domain: String = "com.example.error", function: String = #function, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line) -> NSError {

    let functionKey = "\(domain).function"
    let fileKey = "\(domain).file"
    let lineKey = "\(domain).line"

    let error = NSError(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: [
        NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message,
        functionKey: function,
        fileKey: file,
        lineKey: line
    ])

    // Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)

    return error
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let localizedErrorMessage: String = NSLocalizedString("Unauthorized", comment: "Account not activated")
let error = error(localizedErrorMessage)
```